# Have windows 7 laptop automatically turn on at a set time

Tags: windows-7, laptop, bios, dell-inspiron

I have a dell lnspiron laptop that I am running a minecraft server on and I want it to turn on at a set time in the morning so I don't have to worry about turning it on. I have checked the bios menu and it has nothing about auto start.  Any ideas?

[image: bios]

[image: advanced]

[image: security]

[image: boot]

Comment: I have only looked into the bios settings. I don't think windows can start the computer when the computer is off.

Comment: What bios is this?

Comment: @Dave the bios it A02

Comment: It appears that your BIOS does not have any wake-up features so, unless you can update your BIOS, you're out of luck...

Comment: You can't do it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only some BIOS's support this feature

Yours does not so you can't do this.

There are lots of Wake on Lan tools out there which *may* suffice as a work around.